# TV movie where an inconspicous truck transporting valuables is intercepted by terrorists in a dead radio spot

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

Timeframe: 80/90s
Country: USA

The two protagonists are transporting a MacGuffin in an inconspicous truck which approximately looked like this:
[image]
The truck was internally armored and bulletproof, it had a turbo-/supercharger which could be activated by a security switch and allowed very fast driving (estimate: 150 mph/ 250 km/h) and under the round hood on the top of the driver cabin was a hidden maneuverable gun. The drivers are in steady contact with the headquarters over radio. **This is also the part I am 100% positive that it is correct.** Unfortunately despite being standing out, I was unable to find any flick having a fast truck with a gun on the top.

Whatever the MacGuffin is (I do not remember), it is not money. I am not sure the truck was escorted, but I think so. The villains are portrayed as terrorists in this case; indicators were that the whole operation was not a normal transport (else they simply could have used a normal APC or armored transport for this case), the villains had access to confidential information, they acted ruthlessly and intelligently (kidnapping a family and risking their lives is something which criminals are wary to do, robbers who do this are mostly not exceedingly bright) and lastly they fought to the death (criminals will normally give up after they recognize they are outclassed). Their actions had the whiff of the True Believer. There were 6-12 villains.

The group of terrorists including at least one woman (rare for the 80s, possibly even the leader of the group) kidnap a family and place them on the street so the truck must stop (eventually taking out the escort?) in a dead spot without radio contact. I think it was near an electricity station, the location was, if I must guess, in the middle/north USA (Nebraska et al). Once stopped, the terrorists are jumping the truck from the sides and damage it with explosives so badly that the truck systems are shut down and the protagonists are helpless. The gun can still fire, but the mounting is permanently damaged and the gun cannot be aimed anymore. Because they are in a dead spot, headquarters has no clue that the situation is compromised.

After having the MacGuffin, the terrorists flee in cars and at least one pickup. But our protagonists are able to get the truck running again and even better, to activate the switch so they can outrun the terrorists. Fight, win, terrorists dead, family safe, happy end.

The whole setting has a TV movie touch (but a better one), I am quite sure it isn't a movie production. Nate Eldredge asked if it could be one of the crimefighter series; while I wouldn't bet my life against it, it does not feel right. My fallible memory tells me the movie was standard length (~90 min), the pacing and the background music wasn't right, it wasn't a pseudodoc with a dramatic voice from the off and if the Hoff would have appeared, I would surely remember **that**, you know, German .... :o)

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [Identify-This-X Questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How big was the truck? Was it a big rig or as it had a gun on top was it more like an APC? Any additional information like that could help ID it

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie?  It seems like a plausible episode of any of several '80s cop / crimefighter series (Knight Rider, CHiPS, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Time Bomb

From what I can glean, this seems to be [Time Bomb (1984)](https://letterboxd.com/film/time-bomb-1984/).

IMDb: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088273/combined

[image]

Comment: That looks extremely promising. 80s TV movie, truck, cannon on cabin, female terrorist leader, plutonium....I am pretty sure you nailed it. But I look if I can find a trailer and confirm it finally.

Comment: @ThorstenS.15 second promo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFG5QpDLiRg

Comment: Confirmed, you found it. Now the interesting thing is how many points I got right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the movie is "Time Bomb" from 1984.

For all who want to know how close the description was:
*Timeframe: 80/90s*  **Correct**: 1984
*Country: USA*       **Correct**

*The two protagonists are transporting a MacGuffin in an inconspicous truck.*
**Correct, the MacGuffin is**

> weaponized plutonium.

*which approximately looked like this*
**Wrong**
[image]
Erm, it is a truck, yes....

*The truck was internally armored and bulletproof, it had a turbo-/supercharger which could be activated by a security switch and allowed very fast driving (estimate: 150 mph/ 250 km/h) and under the round hood on the top of the driver cabin was a hidden maneuverable gun. The drivers are in steady contact with the headquarters over radio.*

**Correct.**

> The armor hold up to 0.5" (12,7 mm) bullets, there is a hidden maneuverable gun and during the chase the truck hits at least 113 mph.**

*[..]. I am not sure the truck was escorted, but I think so. The villains are portrayed as terrorists in this case; [...], the villains had access to confidential information, they acted ruthlessly and intelligently (kidnapping a family and risking their lives is something which criminals are wary to do, robbers who do this are mostly not exceedingly bright) and lastly they fought to the death (criminals will normally give up after they recognize they are outclassed). Their actions had the whiff of the True Believer. There were 6-12 villains.*

**Almost completely correct.**

> There was an escort in a car with two people which was taken out, the villain are in fact terrorists, but there were a bit more than 12.

*The group of terrorists including at least one woman (rare for the 80s, possibly even the leader of the group)*

**Correct**.

> The leader is Renee DeSalles played by Morgan Fairchild, a worthy adversary.

*kidnap a family and place them on the street so the truck must stop*
**Partially incorrect.**

> Yes, the terrorists kidnap a family, but the ambush was a fake accident.
>  The family is used as living shields later.

*(eventually taking out the escort?) in a dead spot without radio contact. I think it was near an electricity station*

**Correct**.

> Yes, the escort was killed and it was a dead spot near an electricty station.

the location was, if I must guess, in the middle/north USA (Nebraska et al).
**Wrong.**

> It was Texas.

*Once stopped, the terrorists are jumping the truck from the sides and damage it with explosives so badly that the truck systems are shut down and the protagonists are helpless. The gun can still fire, but the mounting is permanently damaged and the gun cannot be aimed anymore. Because they are in a dead spot, headquarters has no clue that the situation is compromised.*

**Completely correct**.

For all who did not see the movie, I can really recommend it. Both Billy Dee Williams as Wes Tanner and Morgan Fairchild as terrorist are playing quite good.

Comment: Doesn't say the movie title.  This is just purely cross-referencing OP's memory with what they guessed.

Comment: @JMac I **am** the OP. I only added this answer to show how good the estimate was and yes, it is Time Bomb, so I added it now. Please point out the rule that it is forbidden to compare the description with the actual movie.

Comment: I didn't say it was against the rules; it just wasn't really clear what the intent of the answer was.  Still isn't really clear to me.